# UPLOAD query mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am here with another problem.

I am trying to do an UPLOAD query to my database and even though no problem appeared after the process, in my database nothing happened no record was changed.

Where could the problem be?

Here my code:

```html
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

include('link.php');


$_SESSION ['id_user'];

$UserId=$_SESSION ['id_user'];

  $profileUsername= $link->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
  $profilePassword= $link->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
  $profileConfPassword= $link->real_escape_string($_POST['confirm_password']);
  $profileAddress= $link->real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
  $profilePostcode= $link->real_escape_string($_POST['postcode']);
  $profileTown= $link->real_escape_string($_POST['town']);
  // $country= $link->real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
  $profileTel= $link->real_escape_string($_POST['telephone']);
  $profileEmail= $link->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);


  $sqlUpdate="update customers set address= $profileAddress, postcode=$profilePostcode, town=$profileTown, telephone=$profileTel, 
   email=$profileEmail, username=$profileUsername, password=$profilePassword, confirm_password=$profileConfPassword
  
where id_costumer=".$UserId;


   echo $sqlUpdate;


  $link->query($sqlUpdate);
```

Thanks in advance.

Fanjo

Answer (score 0):

The values of those fields should be surrounded with ' single-quotes* like `address='$profileAddress'`

Comment: *"single-brackets"* ? Those are called "quotes", not "brackets".

Comment: I tried with single-brackets too but i doesn't work.